# select product with modal - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get the "modal" layer to take the products / name from the list created by foreach

**is there any way to do this job?**

89/5000
the problem is that when I click on a product it always takes the same, never different

```html
@extends('../layouts.apx')

@section('content')



@foreach($products as $product)
<div class="card mb-4 border-bottom-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mimodalejemplo">
 
    <div class="card-header text-center">{{ $product->name }}</div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <h4>${{ number_format($product->price,2) }}</h4>
        <p>{{ $product->description }}</p>
        <p>{{ $product->extract }}</p>
        <div>

          
            <span class="badge badge-primary"># PROMOCION </span>
           

        </div>
    </div>
 
</div>
@endforeach
<div class="container">
   

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="mimodalejemplo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
   
            <h4 class="modal-title text-dark text-center" id="myModalLabel"> <b>{{ $product->name }}</b></h4>
            
          </div>
     
          <div class="container"><p class="text-secondary text-center">Carne, Queso Cheddar, Tomate, Ajo, Mayonesa Casera, Pan</p></div>
          
          
           <div class="cantidad">
            
             <div class="form-group text-center">
               <label class="col-form-label" for="inputSuccess"> CANTIDAD</label>
               <input type="number" class="form-control is-valid mx-auto col-4" id="inputSuccess" placeholder="1">
             </div>
            </div>
         


       
          <div class="modal-footer">
           <td>
            <a href="{{ route('cart-add', $product->slug) }}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-block bg-success text-white btn-sm">Agregar a mi pedido</button></a>
           </td>
           <a href="">  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button></a>
           
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

 </div>
@stop
```

**I don't know if I should add another foreach, I can't do it by myself, help please**

Comment: Your `$product` variable doen't make sense out of your `@foreach` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$product` variable doesn't make sense out of your `@foreach` loop

You need to create a different modal for each of your products. Something like that will do the trick (take note of the unique Modal id: `mimodalejemplo_{{ $product->id }}`)

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <div class="card mb-4 border-bottom-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mimodalejemplo_{{ $product->id }}">

        <div class="card-header text-center">{{ $product->name }}</div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="mimodalejemplo_{{ $product->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-dark text-center" id="myModalLabel"> <b>{{ $product->name }}</b></h4>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```